# How to enter BIOS or boot menu of Lenovo IdeaPad Yoga 11?

Tags: bios

Volume up + win key (on the screen, not on the keyboard) didn't help.

How can I enter the BIOS on a Yoga 11? Model name 2696. I just want to install a Windows 8 64bit on it from USB stick.

I cannot remove the battery, since it has a built-in one.

I cannot disassemble this notebook, since I don't have the special screwdriver that it needs.

UPDATE: I tried pressing volume up+win key (win key on the screen) + pressing power:

[image]

Comment: What OS was already installed? If it's Windows 8 then you'll probably need to use the Windows 8 `Advanced Startup` options to get to the UEFI interface.

Comment: and what happens if the OS is corrupt?

Comment: If you have a USB that contains a bootable Windows 8 installer image then you should be able to plug the USB in and follow the `hold volume up + Win` keys during boot and it'll take you to boot from USB. From here you should be able to access the UEFI and/or repair your Windows install. As seen here: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Force-Yoga-11-USB-boot/m-p/1093191#M10370

Comment: Normally, the keys to enter BIOS at boot are Escape, F2, F9-F12. When I have a problem, I usually hit all Fn keys, slowly and one at a time, until I find the right one. Like I said, only Escape is an alternative to the Fn keys to enter BIOS.

Comment: I have this laptop. Beside the power button is another physical button. You need to press this to boot into the OS. I will assume you're changing the F buttons :)

Comment: You either use `Advanced Startup` or you fail to boot Windows 3 times.  This is true for ALL Windows 8.x machines.  If the OS is corrupt, then it would fail 3 times, very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution was a hammer. R.I.P. Yoga 11.

[image]

Comment: While this maybe shows what you've done, maybe you can consider moving the green mark ("most helpful answer") to [gogoud's anwer](http://superuser.com/a/970389/287473).

Answer (score 6):

On Lenovo ideapads, If hotkey is enabled use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> for bios setup and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd> for boot menu.

If hotkey is disabled then <kbd>f2</kbd> and <kbd>f12</kbd>. Press the key(s) and power on while still pressing it.

If you need to boot from cd then insert CD before shutdown and power on with <kbd>f12</kbd>. The CD option will appear if CD is inserted. Hotkeys are disabled or enabled in bios setup.

Answer (score 5):

For Lenovo Ideapad or Yoga machines: power it down and then start it *using the Novo button*. This is the tiny button to the left of the power button and you should then see options which allow you to choose the Boot Device, enter BIOS etc.

You could also see [page 26 of the manual](https://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/yoga13_ug_en.pdf)

If your Yoga does not have a Novo key (applies to some early models) then you should be able to get into these settings by pressing the F12 key repeatedly after booting.

Comment: I've given a plus 1 but, not sureif I agree with `once it is down it's a good idea to remove power lead and battery briefly to ensure it really has gone off` - what is the reason for this?

Comment: Because often Windows 8 does not really fully shutdown when you shut it down, so when it starts up it jumps straight back to the existing Windows 8 instance. You can overcome this by holding down the Shift key when you select 'Shut Down' (and ?maybe keep it held down), then it should shut down completely.

Comment: The Novo key powers up the laptop, ignoring Windows 8 fast boot option